# Dart : How to Check if a variable type is String

Tags: dart

I have this code . The class is generic and when I instantiate it by passing a String Type. The variable becomes a string type. However the statement

```
if(_val is String){
}
```

doesnt seem to be true. Any idea why ?

This is the full code:

```
    class foo<T>{
    T _val;
    QVar()
    {
         //Read the value from preferences
         if(_val is String){
            ... //Does not come in here!!
         }
    }
  }

 a   = new foo<String>();
```

Comment: You should probably being doing `if(_val is String)` instead of `if(T is String)`. Most compilers will provide some warning/error reading something along the lines of `T is a type but is being used as a value`. Thereafter, the compiler will infer the type of `_val` to be `String` only inside the `if` block.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. Also any idea how i can do an explicit cast in dart ?

Comment: not sure how to use .cast in this case

Comment: The `as` operator. https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Instead of

```
if(T is String)
```

it should be

```
if(_val is String)
```

The `is` operator is used as a type-guard at run-time which operates on identifiers (variables). In these cases, compilers, for the most part, will tell you something along the lines of `T refers to a type but is being used as a value`.

Note that because you have a type-guard (i.e. `if(_val is String)`) the compiler already knows that the type of `_val` could only ever be `String` inside your `if`-block.

Should you need to explicit casting you can have a look at the `as` operator in Dart, https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators.

Comment: I did the `  if(_val is String)` but looks like it is not going into the conditional statement. I updated my code

Comment: This is because `_val` is never initialised. Remember that `Strings` are reference types and will be `null` if not initialised. That means `null` is a special type and your `if`-statement will be false. Try initialising `_val`. Have a look at this https://gist.github.com/ethanae/f23f883e1ce2394ce078ddba5db4a8d1

Comment: ah ok. Let me try initializing it. Thats what i was thinking too

Comment: Nitpick: The compiler will not type-promote `_val` to `String` here because `_val` is not a local variable.

Answer (score 10):

Use `.runtimeType` to get the type:

```
void main() {

var data_types = ["string", 123, 12.031, [], {} ];`
  
for(var i=0; i<data_types.length; i++){

    print(data_types[i].runtimeType);

    if (data_types[i].runtimeType == String){
      print("-it's a String");

    }else if (data_types[i].runtimeType == int){
      print("-it's a Int");
      
    }else if (data_types[i].runtimeType == [].runtimeType){
      print("-it's a List/Array");

    }else if (data_types[i].runtimeType == {}.runtimeType){
      print("-it's a Map/Object/Dict");

    }else {
      print("\n>> See this type is not their .\n");
    } 
}}
```

Comment: Love this thank you